# Hi-res PNG file in ipad's safari

Tags: ipad, safari, png

I have some asp.net site that shows png images that converted from hi-res tiff files.
The image is shown via simple img tag. The problem is that wneh png has a big resolution - it does not shown properly in ipad's safari browser, but the most of png files are ok.
What it can be?
Thank you

Comment: Unless you post screenshots of how it is not showing properly, you are unlikely to get any help. As-is, there is not enough information in your question to try to formulate an answer.

Comment: It is little question icon instead of image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iPad cannot display images with a w*h larger than 3*1024*1024 (3145728)

So if your image is 2048x2048 then w*h = 4194304 which is larger than 3145728.

<sub>Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15</sub>

Comment: Betamax, is this then perhaps the reason why iPad does not show background images that are put in a sprite image?

Comment: If the image is larger than the size defined above, then yes the iPad would not display the image if it was a background image.

Comment: @betamax is there any source for this info? Which iPad versions does this apply to?

Comment: Apologies, I don't remember where I found this out. All I know is that I was seeing the issue and that this was what was causing it.

Comment: Here's the source: [Apple Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) - Scroll down to the page where it says "Know iOS Resource Limits".